# Getting expand items count with Odata v4.0.30319

Tags: c#, jquery, odata, expand

I am using Odata runtime version v4.0.30319 and trying to get expanded items count in similar query

```
http://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/Categories?$select=Name,Products&$expand=Products
```

I am trying the below way. Do we have any option with odata to find out expanded items count?

```
http://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/Categories?$select=Name,Products($count=true)&$expand=Products
```

Comment: Why not count items client side ?

Answer (score 3):

The correct syntax should be :

http://services.odata.org/v4/OData/OData.svc/Categories?$select=Name&$expand=Products($count=true)

But it seems the demo service doesn't support it.

Comment: This feature hasn't yet been implemented in the OData WebApi framework. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28967908/odata-query-option-count-in-expand-not-working

Comment: This feature is working in the OData WebApi framework, but has not been enabled in the demo service as noted by @karata. Verified in Odata v4.0.30319 as requested!