# OData query option $count in $expand not working

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-web-api-odata, odata-v4

I tried to use [$count in an $expand](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/part1-protocol/odata-v4.0-errata02-os-part1-protocol-complete.html#_Toc406398308) like this query

```
.../OData/Foo(1)?$expand=Bars($count=true)
```

However count is no where to be found in the result.

```
{
  "...": "...",
  "Bars": {
    "...": "..."
  }
}
```

No error either. I'm using ASP.NET Web API OData 5.4, which is using OData v4.

What gives? Not implemented yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature hasn't been implemented yet. A related issue has been created https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/165 .